# Unicode support in regular expression during group capturing in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode

I am currently using re2,re and pcre for regular expression matching in python. when I use regular expression such as re.compile("(?P(\S*))") it is fine and compiled without error but when I use with unicode character such as re.compile("(?P<årsag>(\S*))") then there will be error and can not be compiled. Is there is any python library that support unicode completely.

**edit** : Please refer my output:

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.compile(r"(?P<årsag>(\S*))")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/regex.py", line 331, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/regex.py", line 499, in _compile
    caught_exception.pos)
_regex_core.error: bad character in group name at position 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the external regex module. `regex` module would support Unicode character in the name of named capturing group.

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.compile(r"(?P<årsag>(\S*))")
>>> m.search('foo').group('årsag')
'foo'
>>> m.search('foo bar').group('årsag')
'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks but still it is not supported...still there is error "_regex_core.error: bad character in group name at position 10".any changes need to apply?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.9  in mac

Comment: Please refer my output mention above with question.